# Как стилизовать фон вокруг кнопки

Tags: css

Подскажите пожалуйста как стилизовать фон вокруг кнопки. Мои попытки скруглить фон border-radius привело, что закругления грубые и не так как на картинке

[image]

Comment: "Мои попытки" - ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

border-radius: 45px;

или около того на глаз. Если нет желания делать задний фон дивом, попробуйте тенью, в свое время выкрутился таким образом. Попробуйте box-shadow как вариант и он позволит сгладить с помощью размытия углы. Как-то так.

Comment: спасибо, а то я % использовать пытался

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста и удачи в работе)